# Add a custom block quote for sublime3 for phpdoc

Tags: coding-style, comments, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I tried to write like this

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+;"], "command": { "characters": "/**@var*/", "block": true} }
```

But seem it totally not achieving what the simplest thing I try to do.

What I want the shortcut to do is that once triggered, I wish to enter text formatted like this

```
/**
  *@var
  */
```

Does anyone know how to define such custom shortcut?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this, depending on what functionality you want. If all you want is to print ***exactly*** what you indicated, then create the following snippet:

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
/**
  * @var $0
  */
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>vardoc</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

To do so, create a new file with XML syntax, paste the above exactly as shown, then save the file as `Packages/User/vardoc.sublime-snippet` where `Packages` is the directory opened when you select `Preferences -> Browse Packages`. To trigger the snippet, type ***`vardoc`*** and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Your cursor will be positioned where the `$0` is in the snippet.

This should work fine, except you'll have to type `*` if you need a new line, and there's nothing intelligent about it. Instead, what I'd recommend is [`DocBlockr`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/DocBlockr), a Sublime Text plugin that auto-generates documentation for several languages, including PHP. Typing ***`/**`*** and hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> will give you

```php
/**
 * |
 */
```

Where `|` is your cursor position (this is also a built-in Sublime feature, I believe). It can also auto-document functions. If you have

```php
function foo(MyClass $cls, 
            Array $arr, 
            $num=42, 
            $val=false, 
            $str="sweet function, dude!") {

    return $something;
}
```

and you place your cursor on the line above the function definition and type ***`/**`*** and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, you'll get

```php
/**
 * [foo description]
 * @param  MyClass $cls
 * @param  Array   $arr
 * @param  integer $num
 * @param  boolean $val
 * @param  string  $str
 * @return [type]
 */
```

with `[foo description]` highlighted so you can enter your own description. Hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> again will subsequently highlight `MyClass`, `Array`, etc. so you can alter them if you wish.

More to your question, you can declare a variable

```php
var $foobar = "I love unicorns";
```

Placing your cursor above that declaration and entering ***`/**`*** <kbd>Tab</kbd> will give you

```php
/**
 * [$foobar description]
 * @var string
 */
```

There are other features of `DocBlockr` as well, check out the link above for more details.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Sounds like a really powerful solution thanks : D will try it out now!